# React Downshift useCombobox Hook: Dropdown Not Closing on Outside Clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, downshift

For some reason clicking outside the dropdown with out selecting item, dropdown is not closing

Doesn't downshift by default closes when click outside the rendered dropdown?
I am using react-virtual to render the option. As i am looking over, i feel like isOpen prop that downshift provide is not getting applied properly, but i don't know where to use it.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, ReactNode, useCallback, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { useCombobox } from 'downshift'
import { useVirtual } from 'react-virtual'
import cx from 'classnames'
import './single-select.css'
import { getSingleSelectFilteredItems, groupItemsByKey } from './helpers'
import { SearchSmall, SortArrownDown } from '../icons'
import { TextInput } from '../form'

export interface ComboBoxProps<T> {
  filterKeys: string[]
  groupBy: string
  items: T[]
  itemToString: (item: any | null) => string
  optionListWindowHeight: number
  placeholder: string
  renderRow: (item: T, index: number, props: any) => ReactNode
  setOpenDropdown: (value: boolean) => void
}
const SingleSelectDropdownWithAccordions = forwardRef(<T extends { id: string }>({
  filterKeys,
  groupBy,
  items,
  itemToString,
  optionListWindowHeight,
  placeholder,
  renderRow,
  setOpenDropdown,
}: ComboBoxProps<T>, ref) => {
  const listRef = useRef(null)
  const processedItems = groupBy ? groupItemsByKey(items, groupBy) : items
  const [inputItems, setInputItems] = useState(processedItems)
  const [expandedHeaders, setExpandedHeaders] = useState<Record<string, boolean>>({})
  const rowVirtualizer = useVirtual({
    size: inputItems.length,
    parentRef: listRef,
    estimateSize: useCallback(() => 35, []),
    overscan: inputItems.length,
  })

  const {
    isOpen = false,
    getMenuProps,
    getInputProps,
    getItemProps,
    highlightedIndex,
    selectedItem,
  } = useCombobox({
    items: inputItems,
    itemToString,
    onInputValueChange: ({ inputValue }) => {
      let newItems
      if (inputValue) {
        newItems = getSingleSelectFilteredItems(inputValue, items, groupBy, filterKeys)
      } else {
        newItems = groupBy ? groupItemsByKey(items, groupBy) : items
      }
      setInputItems(newItems)
    },
    scrollIntoView() { },
  })

  return (
    <div className="cz-single-select">
      <TextInput
        icon={<SearchSmall />}
        {...getInputProps()}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
      <ul
        {...getMenuProps({ ref })}
        className={`cz-single-select__window ${isOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}`}
        style={{ maxHeight: optionListWindowHeight }}
      >
        {rowVirtualizer.virtualItems.map((virtualItem) => {
          const itemProps = getItemProps({
            item: inputItems[virtualItem.index],
            index: virtualItem.index,
          })
          const item = inputItems[virtualItem.index]

          if (item.header) {
            const isExpanded = expandedHeaders[item.header]

            const handleHeaderClick = () => {
              setExpandedHeaders((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                [item.header]: !prev[item.header],
              }))
            }
            return (
              <>
                <div
                  {...itemProps}
                  className="cz-single-select__window--accordion-header"
                  role="menuitem"
                  tabIndex={0}
                  key={virtualItem.index}
                  onClick={handleHeaderClick}
                  onKeyDown={handleHeaderClick}
                >
                  {item.header}
                  <span className="cz-single-select__expander-indicator">
                    {isExpanded ? <SortArrownDown /> : <SortArrownDown />}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <p>hi</p>
              </>
            )
          } else if (!expandedHeaders[item[groupBy]]) {
            return renderRow(item, virtualItem.index, {
              ...itemProps,
              className: cx(
                'cz-single-select__option-row',
                highlightedIndex === virtualItem.index && 'cz-single-select__highlighted',
                selectedItem === inputItems[virtualItem.index] && 'cz-single-select__selected',
              ),
              onClick: () => setOpenDropdown(false),
              onKeyDown: () => setOpenDropdown(false),
            })
          }
          return null
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
})

export { SingleSelectDropdownWithAccordions }
```

usages

````
  const [openDropdown, setOpenDropdown] = useState(false)

{openDropdown && (
                    <SingleSelectDropdownWithAccordions
                      items={items}
                      itemToString={
                        (item) => (item ? item.name : '')}
                      renderRow={(item, index, props) => {
                        return (
                          <li
                            {...props}
                            key={index}
                            tabIndex={0}
                            role="menuitem"
                            onClick={() => handleItemSelected(item)}
                            onKeyDown={() => handleItemSelected(item)}
                          >
                            <span>{item.name}</span>
                          </li>
                        )
                      }}
                      groupBy="group"
                      filterKeys={['name']}
                    />
                  )}
    ```
````